# jquery - Live search ajax calls as user types but with small delay?

Tags: jquery

Due to environment I would like to constrain this to something small and concise rather than a plugin, unless it's an extension that can be put inline aside other jquery code.

I have this code:

```
$("#txtSearch").live('keyup', function () {
    LoadList(1)     
});
```

I'd like to add a delay such that if a user must wait (as in stop typing) 0.5 seconds before a call is executed.

**So basically if letters are typed with less than X time between consecutive keystrokes no ajax call occurs.**

Is there a tiny concise way to do this with Jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#txtSearch").live('keyup', function () {
    var value=$("#txtSearch").val();
    setTimeout(function(){
          if ($("#txtSearch").val() == value)
          {
                 LoadList(1)      
          }
    },500);
});
```

Comment: For me it loaded the list twice while the next answer with clearTimeout worked perfectly and looked cleaner.

Comment: This indeed actually triggers the function twice, because the previous timeout is not being reset.

Answer (score 23):

Set a timeout and clear it on every keystroke before applying a new one:

```
var timeout;
$("body").on('keyup', '#txtSearch', function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
       LoadList(1); 
    },500);

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/KgRjJ/

Comment: Thank you! I googled for a while and found nothing helpful until this.

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/live/ --
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: @Lingnik Correct, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the autocomplete widget in jQueryUI, which has a delay option:

> The delay in milliseconds the Autocomplete waits after a keystroke to activate itself. A zero-delay makes sense for local data (more responsive), but can produce a lot of load for remote data, while being less responsive.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete

Comment: not necessary. look on my answer.. And, OP wanted to do it without plugins, but you noted it as I see :D

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned Jquery UI is the one plugin available :)

Comment: Although - autocomplete on the text field isn't technically what I'm doing. I am populating a list of items in a div from a ajax call update rather than dropping down a list from the text box as autocomplete.

Comment: You can do that too with autocomplete just by changing the source option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source